# Execute Javascript in selenium and return value

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am using javascript for selenium selenium-webdriver.

My code is:

```
 return_value = driver.execute_script(script)
```

But I don't know, how to return value from my script.

```
const token = await grecaptcha.enterprise.execute('myKey',{})
return token
```

> Illegal return statement

Thank you for any help.

Comment: what is `script` in `driver.execute_script()` ?

Comment: @cruisepandey The script is the JS lines below the python code

Comment: I generally use it like this `driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector("selector here")` and it returns a web element.

Comment: @cruisepandey But in this case it's not an element.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need execute_async_script for those:

```
token = driver.execute_async_script("""
  let [resolve] = arguments
  grecaptcha.enterprise.execute('myKey',{}).then(token => resolve(token))
""")
```